# Moment.js is converting Date to Today date using React Big Calendar

Tags: reactjs, google-calendar-api, momentjs, react-big-calendar

I've got a problem where the date is being converted to today's date even though the date is being parse by moment. It looks like Moment is converting the date to today's date. I believe I am just using the script incorrectly. I'm not familiar with Moment. Any help would be appreciated.

```
export function getEvents (callback) {
request
.get(url)
.end((err, resp) => {
  if (!err) {
    const events = [];
    JSON.parse(resp.text).items.map((event) => {
      events.push({
        start: moment(event.start.date).toDate()|| moment(event.start.dateTime),
        end: moment(event.end.date).toDate() || moment(event.end.dateTime),
        title: event.summary,
      })
    });
    callback(events)
  }
})
```

This is an example of the trace where the "start" date from Google Calendar is in a Timeformat.
[image: U This is an image where the startDate on the JSON is from Google Calendar]

This is the conversion and a trace of the script [image]

Here is the date in real time on the call:

[image]

Comment: what is the value of `event.start.date` and `event.start.dateTime`?

Comment: That's the value in the first picture. Start in the Local Variables screenshot.

Comment: If you are passing `event.start.date` then your `moment(event.start.dateTime)` won't get executed after `||`.

Comment: I tried `moment('2018-06-21T15:00:00-04:00').toDate()` is giving the correct output `Fri Jun 22 2018 05:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)`. Nothing wrong with the momentjs here. Please check your parse logic and received response.

Comment: Ok I will try that. I had some other problem when I did that and it was documented on the GitHub. Will try and and commment it.

Comment: @OwlyMoly. Thank you for the reply. For some reason, the day is getting translated to Today's date. So yesterday it was yesterday's date and today it's todays. Something is really wrong with the API. The date from Google is exactly in the format in the first picture.

Comment: The condition is assessed for either I want conversion on date or date time., I tried your code and it worked on CodePen but the same code is not working on my code.

Comment: @Axwack: Strange! Have you tried to capture the response object and trying your parse method in codepen or sandbox? If that works then I suspect the version of `moment` used in your project. What version of `moment` are you using in your project ?

Comment: @Axwack: Can you paste that response object (`resp.text`) and parse method here or link a codepen or sandbox for it. So that anyone looking into your issue can try logic.

Comment: Here is a copy of the Response.text https://codepen.io/axwack/pen/WyYKmj

Comment: @Axwack: Check this link for the parsing logic that you are after: https://codesandbox.io/s/ywpznzrmv9

Comment: Remember that `map` creates a object whenever used. Use `forEach` when you are just looping over an object.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that fixed this is in the Moment api. Use this :

```
JSON.parse(resp.text).items.map((event) => {
      var start = moment(event.start.dateTime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate();
      var end = moment(event.start.dateTime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate();
      events.push({
        start: start,
        end:  end,
        title: event.summary,
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking into your `resp.text` that provided in comments I created the following parse method to parse your response as the way you wanted. 
Here `response` passed to this method is your `resp.text` which you supplied in comments.

```
import moment from 'moment'

const parseResponse = (response) => {
     const events = []
     response.forEach(obj => {
      obj.items.forEach(
        item => {
          events.push({
            start: moment(item.start.dateTime),
            end: moment(item.end.dateTime),
            title: item.summary
          })
        }
      )
    })
   return events
 }
```

Note: Check the `codesandbox.io/s/ywpznzrmv9` pen if you want to look into `moment` workaround. You can get rid of first forEach block if the `resp.text` is having only one array of object.|

like:

```
const parseResponse = (response) => {
     const events = []
     response[0].items.forEach(
        item => {
          events.push({
            start: moment(item.start.dateTime),
            end: moment(item.end.dateTime),
            title: item.summary
          })
        }
      )
   return events
 }
```

Note: If you stick to using JSON.parse() then change `map` to `forEach`. map creates an object, which is a garbage that you won't need in your case.